# Pinch-to-zoom on EditText in Fragment using SimpleOnScaleGestureListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, pinchzoom

As in the title, i was looking how to create a pinch-to-zoom effect on an EditTextView inside a Fragment.
I've found also a library that is not working proprely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you have to:

Create a ScaleGestureDetector:

```
ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
EditText editTextView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedinstances)
{
    super.onCreate(savedinstances);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new PinchToZoomGestureListener());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Extend the SimpleOnScaleGestureListener, and overriding the onScale method:

```
public class PinchToZoomGestureListener extends
        SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector)
    {
        float size = editTextView.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

        float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));

        float product = size * factor;
        Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
        editTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

        size = editTextView.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));
        return true;
    }
}
```

On the onCreateView method, just do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    editTextView = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return v.performClick();

        }
    });
}
```

When overriding onTouch event, eclipse suggest to call performClick method on the view. If this method is not called, then your edittext is not selectable and you will end having a TextView instead of an EditText.

Since i spend few time and tried many soultions i hope this can help someone :)

Some source are from this question: [Pinch Zooming on textview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314789/pinch-zooming-on-textview-android)