# Zooming text alone inside an android textview

Tags: android, android-animation, textview

I have a text view with numbers displayed on it. It shows a bill amount value. I would like to have a zoom animation on it, on click. The text view is round shaped and presently zooming zooms the entire circular text view. I used an anim file that uses scaleX and scaleY to zoom. But I just want to zoom the text alone when a user clicks on it. How to zoom text alone inside a textview in android and not the entire textview?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can change textSize property in onClick event of the textView. 
[void setTextSize (float size)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(float)) , or this answer may be useful 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20303367/4233036